# Import statement for dagger cannot be resolved

Tags: android, import, dagger, fizzbuzz

I am 'lucky' to have been charged with maintaining a program developed by someone else, and I come across the following problem with an import statement:

```
import com.fizzbuzz.android.dagger.InjectingDialogFragment;
```

which Android Studio cannot resolve. I am totally new to dagger...

I have the following in build.gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.fizz-buzz:fb-android-dagger:1.0.1'
compile 'com.fizz-buzz:fb-android-bluetooth:1.0.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

InjectingDialogFragment is not available in the version you are currently using. Please use compile **'com.fizz-buzz:fb-android-dagger:1.0.3'** instead.

For better understating on how Dagger works you can use this blog http://antonioleiva.com/dagger-android-part-2/

Comment: It says now 'Could not find com.google.android:support-v4:r13'. I tried to add a compile with this, but  doesnt help

Comment: Yes, I have, still the same. Could it be that it somehow conflicts with
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' ?